# Setup Deckard for Gradle. Error with Robolectric test

Tags: android, testing, gradle, robolectric, build.gradle

I'm trying to create a project with [Robolectric deckard-gradle](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle) 
Everything is ok but when I run a robolectric test the build failed with an exception:

```
cd my-project
./gradlew clean test

1 test completed, failed
:testDebug FAILED

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.findClass(AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java:140)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java:98)
at org.robolectric.SdkEnvironment.bootstrappedClass(SdkEnvironment.java:45)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:205)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

On the other hand, when run a Espresso test any error doesn't occurs

**Environment:**

Gradle 1.10

JDK 8

Last update of Android SDK

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this issue, I'll leave an answer here in case it helps anyone else that runs across this post when searching for this error. For me, it was that the version of Robolectric (or more specifically, the version of ASM it relies on) didn't work with Java 8. Upgrading from Robolectric 2.2 to 2.3 fixed this for me.

Comment: I get `Could not find org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT.`

Comment: Sorry, looks like 2.3 stable has been release since this was written. You'll want to use `org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3` instead (without the `-SNAPSHOT`). I edited the answer to reflect the newer package.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The error was caused by a version conflict in the .gradle folder (gradle-1.10 vs gradle 1.11). Deleting the .gradle folder and regenerating gradle fixes the problem.